# find word in not commented code vb.net using regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, vb.net, notepad++, text-editor, find-replace

how can I use search for a word but not in commented text, for example i need to find lines contains datatable but not proceeded by single quote

```
property xxx as datatable
proptery xxx as object 'datatable adasdasdas
'dim x as datatable
dim x as datatable = new xxxx
```

the search result should highlight these lines, as they contains word datatable and its not proceeded by single quote
property xxx as datatable
dim x as datatable = new xxxx

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([^']*datatable.*?)$
```

Have a look at the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xL9uX0/1)

Comment: You could add word boundaries arround `\bdatatable\b`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `((?<!')datatable)`

It uses a negative look behind, and should work, as Notepad uses PCRE regex.

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/gT7eC3/2) for the example.

For the entire line, what about this?

`.*((?<!')datatable).*`

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/gT7eC3/3) for the example

Answer (score 0):

To find the line with `datatable` which is actually a comment and not followed by `= new xxx` use the following regex.

**Regex:** `(?=.*datatable(?!\s+=\s+new\s+.*))'.*$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=.*datatable(?!\s+=\s+new\s+.*))` The nesting of `negative lookahead` inside `positive lookahead` is done t avoid `= new xxx` part followed by `datatable`.
- `'.*$` Matches the rest of comment till end of line.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eQ7bH0/1)**

**Notepad++ Demo**

[image: Notepad++ Demo]